# iPhone RESTful Webservices

Tags: iphone, web-services, rest

I need to create web service in this format in objective c

An example that returns all contacts for a given user might be (where ZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXR= is a Base64-encoded form of username:password, with the required colon separator):

GET /API/Contacts/username HTTP/1.1
HOST: $baseuri:port
Accept: text/xml
Authorization: Basic ZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXR=

How to create web service for this format.Please help.

Comment: So you need to run a HTTP server from your app? Or connect to an external HTTP server?

Comment: @ August Lilleaas Yes I want to connect to an external server from my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSURLRequest`.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://foo.com/API/Contacts/username"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest] initWithUrl:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[req setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setValue:@"Basic ZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXR=" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self] autorelease];
[req release];
```

Then, implement [the delegate methods documented here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to handle the responses.

Comment: @ August Lilleaas Thank you so much.I am muddling with this for the last 3 hours.